# Should I combine IdentityServer and the administration for it into one application or split into two?

Tags: identityserver4

I wonder if there is a recommendation how to handle the administration of the IdentityServer. Is it better to separate the administration part into an own web application and just use the same DB or is it fine to have only one site? If it's the same web site; can I use OAuth to restrict access to the admin pages or should I use another mechanism; e.g. ASP.NET Authentication?

Comment: Can you clarify as to what you mean handle the administration of IDS? You talking about web application? data? infrastructure? etc.

Comment: With administration I mean the administration of clients, users, scopes, ...
The idea is to have webpages which allow to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can do either - the guys behind Identity server have already created a UI for you here - http://www.identityserver.com/documentation/admin-ui/

There are paid for and free versions.

Comment: I only see a trial, not a free edition.  Where is the free one?

Comment: Well, I know that I can do either, but is their a recommendation or are their any pros/cons for one over the other?